# Table Configuration

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, tabulary

I'm new to LaTeX, and I'm currently struggling with trying to create a table for a lab report. The table has to look like this:

[image]

I have tried looking at the `\tabular`, `\tabulary` and `\tabularx` environments, but I just can't seem to figure out how to set up that first row. Can anyone give me some tips on how I can best set up the right hand side so that it has 2 rows as shown, whilst the left hand side takes up one row that is equal in height?

This is what I've tried, but to no avail:

```
\begin{tabular}[C]{6}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Configuration} 
\multirow{2}{*}{Flow rate (L/hour)} &
\multicolumn{2}{*}{Water Temperatures (\degree C)} 
\multicolumn{2}{*}{Pipe Surface Temperatures (\degree C)}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @JM92 Could you please consider adjusting your question title to make it searchable for posterity? There is some good information here, but it is not well-described under the current title, "Table Configuration".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tables are best done with the `booktabs` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}\toprule
Configuration & Flow rate   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Water Temperatures (\si{\degree}C)} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Pipe Surface Temperatures (\si{\degree}C)} \\
              & (L/hour) & Inlet & Outlet & Inlet & Outlet\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}

  10\% & 16 & 44.9 & 24.5 & 39.8 & 23.7 \\
  10\% & 16 & 44.9 & 24.5 & 39.8 & 23.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```